# Maximum value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

In my Oracle database, I have these values in a column:

6.40.123580

10.10.114580

10.10.114582

I would like to perform a MAX() function on this column, but if I take my example, I never get "10.10.114582". It shows me "6.40.123580".

Is there a solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MAX` directly on the string does not work as it compares the values as strings and looks for the greatest first character then the greatest second character, etc. Since `6` (at the start of `6.40.123580`) is greater than `1` (at the start of `10.10.11458?`) then `6.40.123580` is greater when compared as a string.

What you need to do is split the string on the `.` character and then compare the parts numerically.

---

To do this, you can use simple (fast) string functions to find the positions of the `.` separators and then find the sub-strings between those separators to get the numeric components and then take the row with the greatest values in each successive component:

```sql
SELECT version_number,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number,        1, sep1 -    1)) AS major,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number, sep1 + 1, sep2 - sep1)) AS minor,
       TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number, sep2 + 1)) AS patch
FROM   (
  SELECT version_number,
         INSTR(version_number,'.',1,1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(version_number,'.',1,2) AS sep2
  FROM   table_name
)
ORDER BY major DESC, minor DESC, patch DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Or, using (slower) regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT version_number,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(version_number, '\d+', 1, 1)) AS major,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(version_number, '\d+', 1, 2)) AS minor,
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(version_number, '\d+', 1, 3)) AS patch
FROM   table_name
ORDER BY major DESC, minor DESC, patch DESC
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (version_number) AS
SELECT  '6.40.123580' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10.10.114580' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '10.10.114582' FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | VERSION_NUMBER | MAJOR | MINOR | PATCH |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10.10.114582 | 10 | 10 | 114582 |

---

If you particularly want to use the `MAX` aggregation function then you can use `MAX() KEEP ()` to only keep the greatest of the component parts:

```sql
SELECT MAX(version_number) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number,        1, sep1 -    1)),
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number, sep1 + 1, sep2 - sep1)),
         TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(version_number, sep2 + 1))
       ) AS max_version_number
FROM   (
  SELECT version_number,
         INSTR(version_number,'.',1,1) AS sep1,
         INSTR(version_number,'.',1,2) AS sep2
  FROM   table_name
);
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

> | MAX_VERSION_NUMBER |
> | --- |
> | 10.10.114582 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a80fb8d09ce3892663dcb45aed9c74c9)*